# Android Geofence Dwell-Time not triggering

Tags: android, time, geofencing, android-geofence

I've recently updated Google-Play-Service Library as some classes require for geofencing and GCM were removed/deprecated. I've downloaded the sample code for geofencing from
[Creating and Monitoring Geofences](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

the sample code only monitor the Entry and the Exit , what I've done is added  Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL and set the loitering time also in my IntentService Ive provided logic to handle

```
geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL
```

Geofence on Enter/Exit is working fine but Dwell_TIME is not triggering. 
I've set the geofences as

```
mGeofenceList.add(new    Geofence.Builder().setRequestId(geo_cord.getJSONObject(i_arrcords).getString("store_id"))                         
.setCircularRegion(
                                           Double.valueOf(geo_cord.getJSONObject(i_arrcords).getString("lat")),
                                          Double.valueOf(geo_cord.getJSONObject(i_arrcords).getString("longtd")),
                                  Float.valueOf(geo_cord.getJSONObject(i_arrcords).getString("radius"))

                                )

.setExpirationDuration(Constants.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                                 .setLoiteringDelay(  Integer.valueOf(geo_cord.getJSONObject(i_arrcords).getString("dwelltime")) )  

.setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |   
Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL |        
Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
.build());
```

My intent service as

```
GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
Log.d(TAG, errorMessage);
return;
}

    // Get the transition type.
int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();        

if ((geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL))
{
Log.d(app_tag,GeoStrings.geofence_transition_dwell);    
task_geo_dwell  task_geofence_d=new task_geo_dwell();
task_geofence_d.execute();
}
```

Unfortunately am getting no output in the log and `GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL` never triggered. Please help me out people.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do any updates ? I am also facing similar issue. According the documentation:

Alerts can be late. The geofence service does not continuously query for location, so expect some latency when receiving alerts. Usually the latency is less than 2 minutes, even less when the device has been moving. If the device has been stationary for a significant period of time, the latency may increase (up to 6 minutes).

Comment: Any news regarding this thing?

Answer (score 3):

GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL is triggered only when you enter a geofence and stayed there for the time set using setLoiteringDelay before exiting the geofence.

Another point is that you have to specify initial triggering options as GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL along with GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER . Check the code below:

```
try {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER |GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);

        final Geofence geofence= new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("geofence1")
                .setCircularRegion(lat, lng,radius)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .setLoiteringDelay(20000)
                .build();

        builder.addGeofence(geofence);
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                builder.build(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess())
                {

                    //do something to show geofence added success;

                }
            }
        });
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you pls share the code where you are creating the geofence request? You must also set the initial trigger to be the DWELL like this:

```
GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    //triggers events only when the user stops for a defined duration within a geofence.
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

The geofence request is an argument for the addGeofences() api. For e.g.:

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                     mGoogleApiClient,
                     getGeofencingRequest(),
                     getGeofencePendingIntent()
             );
```

Answer (score -3):

I suspect that GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL doesn't trigger if GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT was already triggered to same GeoFence object.

Comment: From my tests, you can have both `_DWELL` and `_ENTER` (and also `_EXIT`)